# Pump filling constrained discrete optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, constraints

Given three tanks $A, B, C$ with capacities of $12,8,5$ litres of water each and initial condition tank $A=12$ we want to fill containers $A$ and $B$ to have equal amount of water.

Allowed actions are in both ways, chose whichever:

1. $A\iff B$
2. $B\iff C$
3. $C\iff A$

These actions drain/fill the tank to the maximum depending on whether capacity allows, i.e. say if:

a) IC $(A, B, C)=(2, 5, 5)$,

perform Left-Right action 3. $C\implies A$,

the state becomes $(A, B, C)=(7, 5, 0)$

b) IC $(A, B, C)=(2, 5, 5)$,

perform Right-Left action 2. $B\impliedby C$,

the state becomes $(A, B, C)=(2, 8, 2)$

I was able to solve the problem intuitively:

$A\implies B,
B\implies C,
C\implies A,
B\implies C,
A\implies B,
B\implies C,
C\implies A$.

However, eager to know how it is possible to somehow construct a system of linear equations or something like this, and generalize the method. Also whether a solution exists is not clear. Moreover, I am unsure which math area is most closely related to this problem, please kindly advise and feel free to edit if necessary!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_pouring_puzzle